# Hash merging behavior

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.8, ruby-enterprise-edition

Is this behavior correct? I'm running some code like the following:

```
@a_hash = {:a => 1}
x = @a_hash
x.merge!({:b => 2})
```

At the end of all that, x's value has been changed as expected but so has the value for @a_hash. I'm getting {:a => 1, :b => 2} as the value for both of them. Is this normal behavior in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, instance variable `@a_hash` and local variable `x` store the **reference** to the same `Hash` instance and when you change this instance (using mutator method `merge!` that change object in place), these variables will be evaluated to the same value.

You may want to use `merge` method that create a copy of the object and don't change original one:

```
@a_hash = {:a => 1}
x = @a_hash
y = x.merge({:b => 2})
# y => {:a => 1, :b => 2}
# x and @a_hash => {:a => 1}
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I suspected that was what's happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@a_hash is link to x. So if You want @a_hash not changed, you should do like this:

```
@a_hash = {:a => 1}
x = @a_hash.clone
x.merge!({:b => 2})
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to clone when it's totally equivalent to `x = @a_hash.merge(:b => 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's normal behavior in ruby (and most other languages). Both `x` and `@a_hash` are references to the same object. By calling `merge!` you change that object and that change in visible through all variables that refer to it.

If you don't want that behavior, you should either not use mutating methods (i.e. use `x = x.merge(...)` instead) or copy the object before you mutate it (i.e. `x = @a_hash.dup`).